# Connecting with a server - implementing a server push

Tags: android, request, server-side, server-push

I'm in the process of developing an android game within a group of people. Our knowledge is very limited. As a part of the game it will be essential for us to have the continuous possibility for updates. To give some context; this will be a pirate based game where by people can go around and dig for treasure on a map. Friends have to be updated when treasure is retrieved and when new treasure is buried.

Rather than setting a time period to send out a request for any changes on the server, we thought it might be good if the server could just push out changes if they occur.

Does this a) Sound like a good idea for what we'll be updating? and if yes, b) What would be the simplest way of implementing this? / If it is not simple should we stick with the first idea of just sending requests every so often?

Answer (score 0):

What I know about implementing a server push is faking the server push. There are two ways of doing this. One is continuous polling to the server asking for any updates. But when the polling rate is high it will take much network traffic and also will make your application slow. Other way of doing it is to block the client call from the server. When ever a client makes a call to the server, if there is nothing to return server just block that request ( inside a while loop). When ever server has something to return, loop will break and reply the update. But if your network connection is bad you cant do this easily.